# The pressure on touchscreen of Android 4.0

Tags: android, touch, pressure

When I tap the screen of **Android 4.0**, the value of `getPressure()` is always `1.0`. The value is okay on **Android 2.1**. Is there any problem? 
The testing device is **Samsung Galaxy S III**.
The code is like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    float allWidth = this.getWidth();
    float allHeight = this.getHeight();

    calculate(event.getX(), event.getY(), allWidth, allHeight,
            event.getPressure());   
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S III is an Android 4.0 device. Which device on 2.1 do you use that has correct pressure values?

Comment: I used Motorola Milestone to test. It will get the correct value from 0  to 1.